# change value in table a also change in table b

Tags: mysql, triggers, constraints

### Table A

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
    x character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    y character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT A_pkey PRIMARY KEY (x)
)
```

### TABLE B

```
CREATE TABLE B
(
    x character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    z character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    w character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT B_pkey PRIMARY KEY (x,z),
    CONSTRAINT B_fkey FOREIGN KEY (x)
       REFERENCES A (x) MATCH SIMPLE
       ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

---

### Question :

The goal here is that if the value of x changes n table A, that it will also change in table B.
I am not sure if i am doing it right or if i should create triggers for such actions?

Cause now, when i change a vlaue of x in table A, it doesn't change the value of x in table B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was interesting to understand the situation. So, the reason is a MATCH clause in foreign key options. As documentation says, the MATCH causes ON DELETE and ON UPDATE clauses to be ignored.

More information here - [Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

As a solution - recreate foreign key without MATCH SIMPLE clause.

Code example -

```
CREATE TABLE a (
  x VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  y VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (x)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE b (
  x VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  z VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  w VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (x, z),
  CONSTRAINT B_fkey FOREIGN KEY (x)
    REFERENCES a(x) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

INSERT INTO a VALUES
('1', '1'),
('2', '2');

INSERT INTO b VALUES
('1', '1', '1'),
('1', '2', '2'),
('2', '2', '2');

UPDATE a SET x = 33 WHERE x = 1;

SELECT * FROM b;

x   z   w
2   2   2
33  1   1
33  2   2
```

Comment: I have just tried this, When i change value of x in table a, it still doesn't change the value of x in table b. I might have to add that i am using phpMyAdmin ?

Comment: I do not think that phpMyAdmin is a reason, you may check this on any other tool - mysql client, dbForge Studio, the result will be the same. I have added an example which works for me, try to run it.